# Is it possible to get the RequestMethod-verb in a custom PreAuthorize method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I'm using a custom access checker with @PreAuthorize:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class Users {

    @PreAuthorize("@customAccessChecker.hasAccessToMethod('USERS', 'GET')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    User getUsers() {
        ...
    }

    @PreAuthorize("@customAccessChecker.hasAccessToMethod('USERS', 'POST')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    User addUser() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to get rid of the strings 'GET' and 'POST' in the @PreAuthorize annotation. Is it possible to get the RequestMethod used in the @RequestMapping as a variable input to hasAccessToMethod somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot remember an SpEL expression to get data from an annotation, but you can use SpEL to get the value from a parameter of your method with the `#` character. Inject the `HttpServletRequest`, it has a `getMethod` method that contains what you want.

```
@PreAuthorize("@customAccessChecker.hasAccessToMethod('USERS', #request.method)")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
User addUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it's a sane answer. Since an annotation value expects a constant Spring, you can't concatenate it with some enum value.

Comment: From the request I could also get the resource name using #request.servletPath, instead of using the hardcoded 'USERS' string.